# Why won't my app run in Xcode 8 beta (8S128d)

Tags: xcode, xcode8, ios10

This is an issue that will affect many apps, and can be found in Xcode 8 beta (8S128d). This is the first beta, although it is not labelled beta 1.

The issue is with NSUserDefaults; it doesn't work. Here's the code, maybe put it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:@"hello world" forKey:@"TEST"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSString * oops = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"TEST"];
NSLog(@"default = %@", oops);
```

In Xcode 7 and earlier, this code works as expected: the value of `oops` is "hello world".

In Xcode 8, the value of `oops` is `nil`.

That's pretty major!

Comment: Have you posted this as a bug to Apple? Logged in in the developer forums?

Comment: Dev forums weren't working, and anyway most people search stackoverflow first. But it looks like it is a documented issue, albeit with a pretty ugly workaround. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/143155#143155

If you've used Xcode 7 or earlier, you need to reboot the Mac before running the iOS 10 simulator.

> From the release notes:
>
> WWDC Seed: Running multiple iOS simulators
> can cause NSUserDefaults to not work
>
> Running an iOS 8 or 9 simulator
> followed by an iOS 10 simulator will cause NSUserDefaults to stop
> working in the simulator. This can be worked around by rebooting the
> host Mac.

Comment: Interestingly I can NOT find this note in the published release notes for either iOS 10 or XCode 8, which is where I looked first for this issue. The reboot DOES resolve this issue however.

Comment: This is noted as fixed in XCode 8 beta 2, but I have not yet tried it.