# Save dictionary in userdefaults in swift 3 with xcode 8

Tags: nsuserdefaults, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am using the following code to save an object to UserDefaults (previously NSUserDefaults) using xcode 8:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard()
defaults.set(someObject, forKey: "someObject")
print(defaults.object(forKey: "someObject"))
```

someObject is a dictionary and I am running on the simulator.

For some reason this is not saving the value and 'nil' is printed.  Wondering if it's a simulator problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem seems to be caused by having two versions of xcode/simulator installed.

What worked for me was uninstalling xcode 7 and just keeping xcode 8 beta on my system.  Emptying trash, resetting the simulator and running.  I also restarted my computer.

After following these steps the simulator is able to save to UserDefaults.

Answer (score 81):

For Swift 3

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "user_auth_token")
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_auth_token")!)")
```

Answer (score 43):

Working perfectly here with this..!

```
    let dict:[String:String] = ["key":"Hello"]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "dict")
    let result = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "dict")
    print(result!)
    // Output -> { key:hello;}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is the undocumented-but-known issue that NSUserDefaults/UserDefualts does not work in the iOS 10 simulator if the iOS 8/9 simulator has been previously run.

Rebooting your Mac and going straight to Xcode 8, iOS 10 simulator will fix this issue.

See also: [Why won't my app run in Xcode 8 beta (8S128d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824190/why-wont-my-app-run-in-xcode-8-beta-8s128d/37824276#37824276)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4:-**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let dictionary: [String:String] = ["key":"Value"]  //Dictionary which you want to save

defaults.setValue(dictionary, forKey: "DictValue") //Saved the Dictionary in user default

let dictValue = defaults.value(forKey: "DictValue") //Retrieving the value from user default 

print(dictValue)  // Printing the value
```

Comment: saving Int:String Dictionary you'll get app crash. Only String:String works

Comment: @VitoValov why will it crash if the key of the dict is not string?