# Retrieving String Value from User Defaults in Swift 3

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I have a method that sets a `String` value in `UserDefaults`, but when I try to retrieve the value in a `print` statement, I get `nil`. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

```swift
    static func setPreferredUnitsOfMeasurementSystem(_ system: UnitsOfMeasurementSystem) {
        // system.rawValue is of type String
        UserDefaults.standard().set(system.rawValue, forKey: unitsOfMeasurementSystemKey)
        print(UserDefaults.standard().string(forKey: unitsOfMeasurementSystemKey))
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. Seems like a simulator bug. Restarting your Mac and running JUST the iOS 10 sim seems to fix it. See [Save dictionary in userdefaults in swift 3 with xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825630/save-dictionary-in-userdefaults-in-swift-3-with-xcode-8).