# How to save a multidimensional array to UserDefaults

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

Have created an `Array` like this in Swift

```
var MyArray: [String:[String:[Int]]] = [
    "xx": ["x1": [1, 2, 3], "x2": [4, 5, 6], "x3": [7, 8, 9]],
    "yy": ["y1": [10, 11, 12], "y2": [13, 14, 15], "y3": [16, 17, 18]]


]
```

And I wonder how to save this to the `UserDefaults`

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array, this is a dictionary containing a dictionary containing an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save dictionary in userdefaults in swift 3 with xcode 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825630/save-dictionary-in-userdefaults-in-swift-3-with-xcode-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Eric mentioned in comment this is not a multidimensional array it is nested  dictionary, so you can set it using [`set(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1408905-set) and get dictionary using [`dictionary(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1408563-dictionary).

Save dictionary in `UserDefaults`

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(MyDict, forKey:"DicKey")
```

Retrieve dictionary from `UserDefaults`

```
if let dic = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "DicKey") as? [String:[String:[Int]]]  {
    print(dic)
}
```