# How to check if an element is in an dictionary containing a dictionary containing an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

Creted an Array like this:

```
var MyArray: [String:[String:[Int]]] = [
"xx": ["x1": [1, 2, 3], "x2": [4, 5, 6], "x3": [7, 8, 9]],
"yy": ["y1": [10, 11, 12], "y2": [13, 14, 15], "y3": [16, 17, 18]]

]
```

I want to check if for example "xx" is in the `MyArray`. Tried this but it has an error:

```
if [MyArray].contains("xx"{

                    }
```

But it autocorrects it to this

```
if [MyArray].contains(where: "xx"{

                    }
```

And again it has an error,
any ideas??

Comment: As was pointed out [in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103511/how-to-save-a-multidimensional-array-to-userdefaults), `MyArray` isn't an array, it's a dictionary.

Comment: The error you're getting (btw, it *might* be useful to tell us what the error says) is because your syntax is completely botched. Why are you wrapping your "array" (it's a dict) into a new array? Where's the closing parenthesis for the `contains` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "array" is a dictionary, and you ascertain whether one of its *keys* (key `"xx"`) exists or not, a very straightforward way is simply attempting to access that that particular key of the dictionary.

```
var myDictionary: [String:[String:[Int]]] = [
    "xx": ["x1": [1, 2, 3], "x2": [4, 5, 6], "x3": [7, 8, 9]],
    "yy": ["y1": [10, 11, 12], "y2": [13, 14, 15], "y3": [16, 17, 18]]
]

if let _ = myDictionary["xx"] {
    print("Dictionary contains a key 'xx'")
}
```

W.r.t. your attempted use of `contains` applied to the dictionary: another approach is explicitly checking if the collection of `key`'s to the dictionary `contains` your particular key:

```
if myDictionary.keys.contains("xx") {
    print("Dictionary contains a key 'xx'")
}
```

Or, directly using only the `key` in the `(key, element)` tuple of each dictionary item to check whether a given `key` exist in the dictionary:

```
if myDictionary.contains(where: { $0.key == "xx" }) {
    print("Dictionary contains a key 'xx'")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend for you to use optional binding:

```
var MyArray: [String:[String:[Int]]] = [
    "xx": ["x1": [1, 2, 3], "x2": [4, 5, 6], "x3": [7, 8, 9]],
    "yy": ["y1": [10, 11, 12], "y2": [13, 14, 15], "y3": [16, 17, 18]]

]

if let outerDict = MyArray["xx"] {

    for entry in outerDict {
        print(entry)
    }

}
```

Output:

```
("x1", [1, 2, 3])
("x3", [7, 8, 9])
("x2", [4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: That's not optional chaining. That's optional unwrapping.

Comment: @AlexS about the naming, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828301/how-is-swift-if-let-evaluated/38041086#38041086)

Answer (score 0):

First, MyArray is a dictionary not an array, actually it is a dictionary which key is string and the value is also a dictionary which its key is a string and its value is array of integers.

So, if you want to check if the dictionary contains some key or not, you can do that in the if condition like that:

```
if let value = MyArray["xx"] {
    // do some stuff    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swiftiest way if you don't need the value:

```
if let _ = MyArray["xx"]{
    print("something or do something")
}
```

If you need the value do:

```
guard let someValue = MyArray["xx"]{
   return} else{
   someFunc(someValue)
    someProperty = someValue
}
```