# Exception while setting NSDictionary to UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

How to fix exception:

```
[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
4 = 5;
} as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key MyKey
```

thrown by executing following code (Swift 3)

```
let ns = NSDictionary(dictionary: [4: 5])
UserDefaults.standard.set(ns, forKey: "MyKey")
```

Code above correctly saves `String` type, but has problem with `NSDictionary`

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825630/save-dictionary-in-userdefaults-in-swift-3-with-xcode-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All property list keys are required to be `String`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)

> And although `NSDictionary` and `CFDictionary` objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, **if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects**.

```
let ns = ["4": 5]
UserDefaults.standard.set(ns, forKey: "MyKey")
```

No need to use `NSDictionary`, Swift `Dictionary` works the same way and is implicitly bridged.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary must have strings as keys for you to be able to save it to UserDefaults

this works for me:

```
let ns = NSDictionary(dictionary: ["4": 5])
UserDefaults.standard.set(ns, forKey: "MyKey")
```